# Dependency property not binding to view

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

what im tryin to do is populate a combobox based upon the selected item of a treeview. as depending on what node is chosen will populate the combobox with a different list of report levels.

the combobox is within a user control and i am trying to bind to a dependency property ReportLevel i have in my MainViewModel. if i set the value of the combobox its fine but i want to be able to update it whenever a user choses a different node on the tree.

here is my xaml

```
    <UserControl x:Name="this"
    x:Class="RTHM.ComboboxControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-        compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         xmlns:local ="clr-namespace:RTHM.ViewModels"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

<Grid>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" MinHeight="221.904" Margin="12,12,42,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" MaxWidth="246.226" Width="246">
        <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" MinHeight="224.072" VerticalAlignment="Top" MinWidth="246.13">
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" MinHeight="104.489" Margin="10,289.95,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ReportDescription, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" MinWidth="245.124"/>
            <TextBox MinHeight="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Report Level:" MinWidth="120" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0,0,5,5"/>
            <ComboBox MinWidth="120" Margin="0,0,0,5" MinHeight="23" 

                      ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=this, Path=ReportLevel,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                      DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedLevel, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>
```

my code behind

```
public partial class ComboboxControl1 : UserControl
{
    public ComboboxControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

       DataContext = new MainViewModel();
```

in my MainViewModel i have this

```
    #region DependencyProperties
   public static readonly DependencyProperty LevelProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("ReportLevel",typeof(ObservableCollection<ReportLevel>),typeof(MainViewModel));

    public ObservableCollection<ReportLevel> ReportLevel
   {
       get
       {
           return (ObservableCollection<ReportLevel>)GetValue(LevelProperty);
       }
       set
       {
           SetValue(LevelProperty, value);
       }
   }
```

and have a method which sets the value of this like

```
            ReportLevel = c.GetUserReportLevel();
```

i have tried various things with the ItemSource of the combobox but without success.

Any help on the matter would be appreciated

Thanks,
Marty
EDIT: Have updated my code but still no luck with this matter, any ideas?
Xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="RTHM.ComboboxControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-   compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         xmlns:local ="clr-namespace:RTHM.ViewModels"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

<Grid>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" MinHeight="221.904" Margin="12,12,42,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" MaxWidth="246.226" Width="246">
        <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" MinHeight="224.072" VerticalAlignment="Top" MinWidth="246.13">
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" MinHeight="104.489" Margin="10,289.95,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ReportDescription, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" MinWidth="245.124"/>
            <TextBox MinHeight="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Report Level:" MinWidth="120" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0,0,5,5"/>
            <ComboBox MinWidth="120" Margin="0,0,0,5" MinHeight="23" 

                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Levels}" 
                      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                      DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedLevel, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>
```

and in MainViewModel

```
private ObservableCollection<ReportLevel> _levels;
public ObservableCollection<ReportLevel> Levels
    {
        get
        {
            return _levels;
        }
        set
        {
            _levels = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Levels");
        }
    }
```

my MainViewModel inherits from a base class which has INotifyProperty changed and an implementation

```
public class ViewModelBase :  INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is it a `DependencyProperty` ? a straight Binding to your VM is what you need.

Comment: You are setting the `ElementName` property to your usercontrol (named `this`, which is a bad idea), however you say the `DependencyProperty` is in the ViewModel, and not in the `UserControl`. Have you checked the output window? It should warn about binding errors

Comment: i tried using a regular property implementing INotifyPropertyChanged but that didnt seem to work either and read a few articles saying you have to use DPs for userControls.

Answer (score 1):

The binding

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=this, Path=ReportLevel, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

binds to a `ReportLevel` property in your UserControl. There is however no such property, because it is in the DataContext of the UserControl. The binding should look like shown below. Please also note that a two-way binding on the ItemsSource property doesn't make sense, as the control never *sets* that property.

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ReportLevel}"
```

---

That said, you do usually not have dependency properties in view models. Instad, the view model classes should implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

You also have to actually fire the PropertyChanged event when the `ReportLevel` property changes:

```
private ObservableCollection<ReportLevel> reportLevel;
public ObservableCollection<ReportLevel> ReportLevel
{
    get { return reportLevel; }
    set
    {
        reportLevel = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("ReportLevel");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but my ViewModel does implement IINotifyPropertyChanged from a base class. the binding you have supplied i have already tried that previously but with no luck. it still does not update.

Comment: Sorry but ive already tried that i am aware you need to fire the event. when i used regular properties i went through the code to see if the PropertyChangedEvent was being fired and it was. Thats why im so confused, because if the events are fired, why isnt my view updating if i had the binding you proposed?

Comment: There is also a public property `Name` in class `ReportLevel`? Do you see any binding error in the Output Window in Visual Studio when you run your application? What exactly isn't working?

Comment: yes there is, and yes i have checked for binding errors and there is none

Comment: Might be an oversight but you definitely have items in your list, right?

Comment: Yup, definitely. ive also tried updating simple strings on the page aswell but that isnt working either even when i check that INPC is firing